# Solicitar información a una API externa de forma asíncrona

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo este código en un componente que funciona perfectamente al llamar al servicio, mostrando los resultados leidos en el html correspondiente:

```
this._starshipsService.GetStarShips('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/').subscribe( (data: any) => {
  this.starships = data.results;
```

El servicio se limita a llamar a una API:

```
  GetStarShips(url): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'none'});
    return this.http.get( url, { headers } );
```

Intento aplicar algo parecido al buscador, es otro componente, para poder filtrar los datos recibidos:

```
this.aFound = this._starshipsService.buscarStarShips( this.searchText );
            console.log('resultados encontrados ... ' + this.aFound);
```

El servicio sería algo así, prescindo de los console.log para reducir el código:

```
  buscarStarShips( text: string ): any {
    let aShips: any[] = [];
    let aResultados: any[] = [];

    text = text.toLowerCase();

    this.GetStarShips('').subscribe( (data: any) => {
            aShips = data.results;

            for( let ship of aShips ) {
                    let cShip = ship.name.toLowerCase();
                    if ( cShip.indexOf(text) >= 0 ) {
                      aResultados.push( ship );
                    }
            }
            return aResultados;
          });

  }
```

Estos son los timmings de los procesos, "resultados encontrados" se resuelve sin datos antes de esperar a recibir la respuesta de la API en la que si se encontrarán datos:

```
17:41:40:690 - buscando ... wing
17:41:40:692 - resultados encontrados ... undefined
17:41:40:942 - resultados API: 10 leidos
17:41:40:942 - Y-wing found ...
17:41:40:942 - X-wing found ...
17:41:40:942 - 2 result/s encontrados
```

Seguro que tocará utilizar promises, async y/o await, pero no he conseguido integrar ninguno de los ejemplos encontrados.

Gracias, Xavi

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el `buscarStarShips`. La función no está devolviendo nada. Una de las soluciones es hacer que la función devuelva el Observable:

```js
buscarStarShips( text: string ): Promise<any[]> {
    let aShips: any[] = [];
    let aResultados: any[] = [];

    text = text.toLowerCase();
    
    // Creamos una promesa que se resolverá con la respuesta del servidor
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.GetStarShips('').subscribe( (data: any) => {
              aShips = data.results;

              for( let ship of aShips ) {
                      let cShip = ship.name.toLowerCase();
                      if ( cShip.indexOf(text) >= 0 ) {
                        aResultados.push( ship );
                      }
              }
              // Entregamos el resultado a la promesa
              resolve(aResultados);
            });
      });
  }
```

Y ahora si podés usar:

```js
this.aFound = await this._starshipsService.buscarStarShips( this.searchText );
console.log('resultados encontrados ... ' + this.aFound);
```

Comment: La 1ª vez funciona perfecto, las siguientes búsquedas, si no se recarga la página no funcionan, seguro que es por cómo hago la llamada, esta sería la función que tengo en el componente navbar, no entra en el navigate:
**buscarShip( text: string ) {
console.log('buscar ... ' + text);
    this.SearchRouter.navigate( ['/buscar', text ] );

  }**

Comment: Disculpá @XaviT. la función que estabas usando es `buscarStarShips` no indicas que relación hay con `buscarShip` y el navbar

Comment: Perdonarme, el input de search está en el **navbar**, desde el mismo **navbar** se lanza la función `buscarShip` que simplemente hace un **.navigate** al componente buscador donde se ejecuta el servicio `buscarStarShips`, espero aclare la logística usada.

Comment: Entiendo... El problema está probablemente en el navigate entonces... Pero es un problema diferente... Tendrías que mostrar el codigo del navbar junto con la llamada al navigate

Comment: Este seria el código en el navbar: `ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  buscarShip( text: string ) {
console.log('buscar ... ' + text);
//    this._starshipsService.buscarShips( text );
    this.SearchRouter.navigate( ['/buscar', text ] );

  }`.

Comment: He comprobado que la 2ª búsqueda no llega ni al constructor ni al OnInit del componente buscar a pesar de que la URL si se actualiza con esta 2ª búsqueda. Entiendo que por alguna razón el .navigate no abre la página. Una vez veo que no se abre, si refresco el navegador muestra los resultados de búsqueda correctos. Si cambio de página y hago click en el buscador, entonces si funciona, sería como una 1ª búsqueda.